# Processing POST json data in python flask app on Azure

Tags: python, azure, http, flask

I have a basic python flask app deployed on Azure which I am trying to get to process json data that I am posting to it via a REST client.

Here's the app:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/json', methods=['POST'])
def json():
    req_data = request.get_json()
    data = req_data['data']
    return 'The data is {}'.format(data)
```

The data I am posting:

```
{
    "data":"abc"
}
```

However, when I send a POST request, I get an error message: "500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR". Any idea why this would be?

Comment: Can you confirm that you have a working app by creating another route that uses the `GET` method i.e. just a Hello World route? Also note the answer posted by @JayGong is setting the app up on a Windows server, however python is no longer supported by Microsoft on windows for app services [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-on-azure-app-service?view=vs-2019).

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you? If so,would you please accept it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow my working steps:

Step 1 : Add Extensions(here is Python 3.6.1 x64) in the portal navigation bar.

[image]

Step 2 : Publish your `flask` project and add the `web.config`.

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="<Your Project Name>.app"/>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot"/>
    <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="D:\home\LogFiles\wfastcgi.log"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\home\Python361x64\python.exe|D:\home\Python361x64\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If you deploy successfully, you could see following structure in the `KUDU` path: `D:\home\site\wwwroot>`.

[image]

Step 3: Switch to the Kudu CMD and commands `cd Python361x64` and `touch get-pip.py` and copy the content of the url `https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py` into the `get-pip.py` via Edit button, then run `python get-pip.py` to install the pip tool.

[image]

Step 4 : Install any packages you need via `python -m pip install request`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I've tried adding an extension, however, the menu icon for the extension option has been disabled (greyed out)?

Comment: @Matt Maybe it's about your level of service plan.Is is free level?